# Get API route on an associative entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine

On a Symfony project, I am trying to set up an API route with API Platform.

I have 3 entities: Game, GamePlayer, Player.
Game and Player have a ManyToMany relationship. But since I had to work on the associative table, I have this:

> Game (OneToMany) GamePlayer (ManyToOne) Player

The Api route is: */party/{accessCode}/{pseudo}* 
*accessCode* is a property present in **Game** and *pseudo* in **Player**

the desired result is that, from these two parameters, I obtain the row present in the associative table. As this SQL query does:

```sql
SELECT game_player.* FROM game_player
INNER JOIN player ON player.id = game_player.player_id
INNER JOIN game ON game.id = game_player.game_id
WHERE player.pseudo = "lud" AND game.access_code = "5JAIUENQWR4"
```

I tried to use a Controller (controller: `ApiGamePlayerController::class`) 
and I also defined the variables through `uriVariables`

but I didn't get any conclusive results. Is it at least possible to do this?

Here are my entities:

```
class Game
{
    #[
        ORM\Id,
        ORM\GeneratedValue,
        ORM\Column,
        Meta\ApiProperty(identifier: false)
    ]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[
        ORM\Column(length: 20, unique: true),
        Meta\ApiProperty(identifier: true),
        Groups([
            'game:get:col', 'game:get:code', 'game:post',
            'player:get:col', 'player:get:pseudo'
        ])
    ]
    private ?string $accessCode = null;

    #[
        ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'game', targetEntity: GamePlayer::class, orphanRemoval: true, cascade: ["remove"]),
        Groups([
            'game:get:col', 'game:get:code'
        ])
    ]
    private Collection $players;
}
```

```
class GamePlayer
{
    #[
        ORM\Id,
        ORM\GeneratedValue,
        ORM\Column
    ]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[
        ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'players'),
        ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'game_id', nullable: false),
        Groups([
            'player:get:col', 'player:get:pseudo'
        ])
    ]
    private ?Game $game = null;

    #[
        ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'games'),
        ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'player_id', nullable: false),
        Groups([
            'game:get:col', 'game:get:code'
        ])
    ]
    private ?Player $player = null;
}
```

```
class Player implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[
        ORM\Id,
        ORM\GeneratedValue,
        ORM\Column,
        Meta\ApiProperty(identifier: false)
    ]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[
        ORM\Column(length: 100, unique: true),
        Meta\ApiProperty(identifier: true),
        Groups([
            'player:get:col', 'player:get:pseudo', 'player:post', 'player:patch',
            'game:get:col', 'game:get:code'
        ])
    ]
    private ?string $pseudo = null;

    #[
        ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'player', targetEntity: GamePlayer::class, orphanRemoval: true, cascade: ["remove"]),
        Groups([
            'player:get:col', 'player:get:pseudo'
        ])
    ]
    private Collection $games;
}
```

and here is the header of **GamePlayer**

```
#[
    ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: GamePlayerRepository::class),
    ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: 'game_player_idx', columns: ['game_id', 'player_id', 'leader_id', 'order_turn'])
]
#[
    Meta\ApiResource(
        operations: [
            // new Meta\Get(),
            new Meta\GetCollection(
                controller: ApiGamePlayerController::class,
                itemUriTemplate: '/party/{accessCode}/{pseudo}',
                // uriVariables: [
                //     'pseudo' => new Meta\Link(fromClass: Player::class, fromProperty: 'games'),
                //     'accessCode' => new Meta\Link(fromClass: GamePlayer::class, fromProperty: 'game', toClass: Game::class)
                // ],
                // uriVariables: [
                //     'pseudo' => new Meta\Link(fromClass: GamePlayer::class, fromProperty: 'player', toClass: Player::class),
                //     'accessCode' => new Meta\Link(fromClass: GamePlayer::class, fromProperty: 'game', toClass: Game::class)
                // ],
                normalizationContext: [
                    // 'groups' => ['player:get:pseudo'],
                    'openapi_definition_name' => 'User Game Read'
                ],
                openapi: new Model\Operation(
                    summary: 'Route pour obtenir les informations d\'un joueur sur une partie',
                    description: 'Route pour obtenir les informations d\'un joueur sur une partie',
                )
            ),
            // new Meta\Post(),
            // new Meta\Put(),
            // new Meta\Patch(),
            // new Meta\Delete()
        ]
    )
]
class GamePlayer
{}
```